# Arranging data in csv for use in R

Tags: r, sorting, csv

I'm trying to arrange my data in csv so I can compare in R,  data is yield data with different treatments, added factors and arranged in blocks. Here's a snippet

```
Treatment    mg.kg Biochar.y.n..1.2. Fertiliser.inorg.org..3.4. Block.number
        A 1.045924                 2                          3            1
        A 1.440180                 2                          3            3
        A 1.536620                 2                          3            2
        A 1.563100                 2                          3            6
```

How do I arrange this so that I can compare the treatments (A-E, six replicates of each) against each other accounting for fertiliser/block etc?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear -- do you mean that you have data in a csv already, and you want to compare the treatments in R, or that you want to produce a csv from some other program based on raw data, and you want to know the best way to format it so that it can be read into R?

Comment: I need to produce a csv file from all my excel data and yes, I need to format it so that it can be read properly in R.  I don't seem to be able to arrange the data in such a way that it will compare yield data from the treatments.  I check the format by running a summary(data) on the numbers and then check the results against my original SPSS output (which I trust I can use properly)  I need to use R as I know it has more scope for the analysis I want to do.  Thanks for your repsonse :)

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing exactly what the difficulty is.  If you save as a csv file from excel and use `read.csv()` in R, does this fail?  Can you give some idea of what you've tried so far?